# Best way to select and count rows in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in MS Access like this:

```
number | type  | date  | person |
---------------------------------
3273     | green  | 03/02/2015 | Andre   |
2556     | red  | 02/01/2016 | Roger  |
2556-P     | yellow  | 25/12/2015| Roger |
8354     | green | 18/03/2016| Andre |
6754     | green  | 16/03/2016| Jack |
```

To make this table out of external `.accdb` file in `E:\folder\file_name.accdb`, the following query was executed:

```
SELECT all_data.number, all_data.`date`, all_data.`type`, all_data.`person`
FROM `E:\folder\file_name.accdb`.all_data all_data
```

I previously had only experience with MySQL and PostgreSQL and never with imported tables. I need to select and count unique numbers (those with -P and other letters don't count) for every person, given that the date for those numbers is X/12/2015.

How should I approach this? I tried

```
SELECT all_data.number WHERE 'date' BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 00:00:00' FROM `E:\folder\file_name.accdb`.all_data all_data`,
```

but it didn't seem to work, it complains about my use of `date`.

What should I do and maybe it's better to make use of VBA or this can be done by SQL alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several items arise from your SQL statement that need to adhere to MS Access' SQL dialect:

1. Field names cannot be enclosed with quotes. While in Oracle/Postgres you can use double quotes for column/table identifiers, Access uses square brackets `[date]` or backticks `` `date` `` (usually to escape spaces and reserved words). Note: both *date* and *number* are [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe). Like MySQL, in Access string literals can use single or double quotes.
2. Date values need to be enclosed in `#` (in place of quotes) or wrapped in `CDate()` function.
3. The `WHERE` clause in any SQL query must follow `FROM` and/or `JOIN` clauses.
4. The `LIKE` operator (which you might need to find the `-P` pattern) uses the asterisk and not percent operator (`ALIKE` for ANSI-Like does use `%`). With that said, if you connect to the MS Access database externally via ODBC (not the GUI .exe program), `LIKE` does require `%`.

**SQL** *(all queries below are equivalent)*

```sql
SELECT all_data.number
FROM [E:\folder\file_name.accdb].all_data all_data
WHERE [date] BETWEEN #2015-12-01 00:00:00# AND #2015-12-31 00:00:00#
AND [number] LIKE '*-P'; 

SELECT all_data.number
FROM `E:\folder\file_name.accdb`.all_data all_data
WHERE `date` BETWEEN CDate('2015-12-01 00:00:00') AND CDate('2015-12-31 00:00:00')
AND `number` ALIKE '%-P';
```

Additionally, you can use same format as original string literal, `DD/MM/YYY`, for dates:

```sql
SELECT all_data.number
FROM [E:\folder\file_name.accdb].all_data all_data
WHERE [date] BETWEEN #01/12/15# AND #31/12/15#
AND [number] LIKE '*-P';

SELECT all_data.number
FROM `E:\folder\file_name.accdb`.all_data all_data`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN CDate('01/12/15') AND CDate('31/12/15')
AND `number` ALIKE '%-P';
```

Answer (score 0):

When  using dates in VBA you need to enclose them between pound signs. Like this

```
Dim this as date
this = #01/01/2016#
```